# I am trying an else if statement for validation email however it throws an error on else if(password.isEmpty) saying "else without if"

Tags: android

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    Tmail = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    Tpass = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    Tconfirmpass = findViewById(R.id.loginRetype_password);
    Bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
    button = findViewById(R.id.signin);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email, password, confirm;

            email = Tmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
            password = Tpass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
            confirm = Tconfirmpass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

            if (email.isEmpty()){
                Tmail.getEditText().setError("Field should not be empty");
                Tmail.requestFocus();
            }
            else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches());{
                Tmail.setError("Please enter a valid email Id");
                Tmail.requestFocus();
            }
           else if (password.isEmpty()){
                Tpass.setError("Please enter password");
                Tpass.requestFocus();
            } else if (password.length() < 6) {
                Tpass.setError("Password too short");
                Tpass.requestFocus();
            } else if (!confirm.equals(password)) {
                Tconfirmpass.setError("Password mismatch");
                Tconfirmpass.requestFocus();
            } else {mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }
        }
    });

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please format your code properly.

Delete the semicolon in the line `else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches());` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at this line

```
!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches());
```

you have added accidentally ; at the end which will terminate the flow, remove ; and try again, hope it will work fine